# window.customElements.whenDefined never been resolved when testing with Karma

Tags: javascript, promise, karma-runner, web-component, custom-element

In few words, I need to delay the test until certain element is avaible, For that I am realing in the promisse window.customElements.whenDefined but it is never been resolved.

My Unit Test

```
import { html, fixture, expect } from '@open-wc/testing';

import '../src/skyscanner-flight-search/skyscanner-flight-search.js';

describe('skyscanner flight search', () => {
    it('show div', async() => {
        const el = await fixture(html `
      <skyscanner-flight-search></skyscanner-flight-search>
    `);
        console.debug('before promisse');
        window.customElements.whenDefined('skyscanner-flight-search').then(() => {
            el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#firstdiv2');
            console.debug('after promisse');
            expect(el).to.exist;

        });
    });
});
```

Console:

```
# npm run test

> skyscanner-openwc-graphql@0.0.0 test C:\_d\WSs\rapidapi-vanilla-webcomponents\skyscanner-openwc-graphql
> karma start


START:
14 08 2019 18:23:31.552:WARN [filelist]: Pattern "C:/_d/WSs/rapidapi-vanilla-webcomponents/skyscanner-openwc-graphql/__snapshots__/**/*.md" does not match any file.
14 08 2019 18:23:31.578:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.2.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
14 08 2019 18:23:31.579:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited
14 08 2019 18:23:31.586:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
14 08 2019 18:23:32.908:INFO [HeadlessChrome 76.0.3809 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket jC7mtfb4Iyvm14DFAAAA with id 22187366
DEBUG: 'before promisse'
  skyscanner flight search
    √ show div

Finished in 0.113 secs / 0.006 secs @ 18:23:36 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)

SUMMARY:
√ 1 test completed
```

Relevant piece from Package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@open-wc/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "@open-wc/prettier-config": "^0.1.10",
    "@open-wc/testing-karma": "^3.0.0",
    "@open-wc/testing-karma-bs": "^1.0.0",
    "@open-wc/testing": "^0.11.1",
    "@open-wc/demoing-storybook": "^0.3.0"
},
```

In case it adds something, here is all the source code https://github.com/jimisdrpc/skyscanner-openwc-graphql.git